# Раскрывающийся список и подпунктами

Tags: android

Есть БД с двумя таблицами - radio и category. Хочу вывести их раскрывающемся списком как на рисунке и у меня вопросы

1. Можно ли для этого использовать CardView или RecyclerView и что из них нужно для этого?
2. Если использовать CardView или RecyclerView будут ли они работать на андроид 4.1 и выше?
3. Если первые два вопроса удовлетворяют тому что я хочу сделать, то где можно посмотреть пример реализации того что я хочу?

P.S. Конечно понимаю что можно использовать ExpandableListView, но вроде как RecyclerView получше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `ExpandableListView` - с ним проще будет работать.

1. CardView можно использовать для оформления внешнего вида списка
2. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/expandablelistview.php

Comment: А на старых версиях андроид до 5-го будет работать CardView?

Comment: да, должна быть поддержка меньших версий андроид, возможно не полная поддержка. нужно тестировать. в своем проекте использовал и все работало

Comment: Хорошо, буду пробовать. Спасибо